# Backbone.js iterating through object values in tpl

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm using backbone.js and am curious if it's possible to iterate through a generic object key/values in the tpl. Example:

Model data received from the server:

```
{
   id: "someid",
   data: {
      key1: "some value",
      key2: "some value"
   }
}
```

The tpl I'm using looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-object-list-item">
   <%%= id %> - <%%= data %>
</script>
```

which outputs something like this:

```
someid - [object Object]
```

I know it's possible to use something like <%%= data.key1 %> but I'm wondering if it's possible to iterate through the key/value pairs in data without explicitly calling them out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, by adding a code block to do the iteration:

```
<% for (var key in data) { %>
    <%= data[key] %> 
<% } %>
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Is there more documentation on this?

Comment: @fffanatics there's some minimal documentation on the underscore.js site:  http://underscorejs.org/#template